# Android GMaps v2 - Get location of the center of the map & map height and width

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of the center of the map in the Google Maps V2 API & get the width and length of the map.

Here is my old code(from GMaps v1 that I started to modify):

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

private GoogleMap mGoogleMapView;

public LatLng getMapCenter()
{
  if( mGoogleMapView != null )
  {
     return mGoogleMapView.getMapCenter();
  }
  /*if( mOpenStreetMapView != null )
  {
     return convertOSMGeoPoint( mOpenStreetMapView.getMapCenter() );
  }*/
  return null;
}

public int getHeight()
{
  if( mGoogleMapView != null )
  {
     return mGoogleMapView.getHeight();
  }      
  /*if( mOpenStreetMapView != null )
  {
     return mOpenStreetMapView.getHeight();
  }*/
  return 0;
}

public int getWidth()
{
  if( mGoogleMapView != null )
  {
     return mGoogleMapView.getWidth();
  }
  /*else if( mOpenStreetMapView != null )
  {
     return mOpenStreetMapView.getWidth();
  }*/
  return 0;
}
```

How can I perform the same functionality that mapView.getMapCenter(), mapView.getHeight(), and mapView.getWidth() using the Android GMaps V2 API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting the center:

```
GoogleMap map;
LatLng center = map.getCameraPosition().target;
```

Getting the width and height:

If you're adding the `MapFragment` to your `Activity` using a `FragmentTransaction`, you have to provide some `ViewGroup` to put the fragment into. Something like a `LinearLayout` or such. Calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on such `ViewGroup` should get you what you want.

Hope it helps. If you need an example, let me know.

**EDIT - adding an example:**

Take a look at the [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), especially at the section named: [Add a Fragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=cs#add_a_fragment).

Under the part that starts with *You can also add a MapFragment to an Activity in code*, there is an example. In that example, `R.id.my_container` is exactly the `ViewGroup` I wrote about above. Somewhere in the XML layout of your `Activity`, there is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

What the `FragmentTransaction` does is that it takes a `MapFragment` and puts it as a child of this `LinearLayout`. The only child. Therefore the map has the same width and height as the `LinearLayout`.

Then you can easily get what you need in your `Activity` like this.

```
LinearLayout myContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_container);
int mapHeight = myContainer.getHeight();
int mapWidth = myContainer.getWidth();
```

I hope it's understandable.

Comment: If you could provide an example that would be great.