# How to popup a custom marker info window outside google maps frame on marker click

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, android-coordinatorlayout

i'm developing an app that currently has a main activity with a coordinator layout and some fragments popping in and out. What i want to achieve is while in Google maps fragment, to popup a card or something similar from back in order to show marker detailed info, without the limitations of marker title/snippet.

The current coordinator layout is this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/maincontainer"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
....
/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
....
/>
```

I attach an example from another app to be clearer.

[image]

Comment: try solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678545/how-to-change-info-window-custom-position-in-google-map-v2-android.

Comment: I think it's not what i need, simply moving to bottom the info windows causes the window to be covered by my FABs, what i wanted to achieve is something cnsistent with the coordinator layout. Thanks anyway

Comment: have you tried the [bottom sheet](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031) yet?