# centering the camera in Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In my android app I have the following code...

```
CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Lat,Lon));
DebugLog.debugLog("centered camera on " + Lat + " and " + Lon, false);
    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
map.moveCamera(center);
    map.animateCamera(zoom);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Lat, Lon))
        .title("Phone Location")
            );
```

Lat is 31.7898
Lon is -111.0354

The marker is exactly at the proper location.  However the camera is centered about 5 miles north of that location on the v2 map.
Why?
Thanks
Gary

Comment: Try doing both the center and the zoom in one operation, rather than two.

Comment: Just to show an example of how to do so:   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,
    15));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading some additional docs, I found that the following code worked...

```
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(Lat, Lon))
        .zoom(15)
        .bearing(0)
        .tilt(45)
        .build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(Lat, Lon))
    .title("Phone Location")
        );
```

I think my original code should have also worked.
Gary

Answer (score 3):

Keep the perspective the same, but center camera at the currently clicked marker:

```java
    obj_map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
        CameraPosition obj_cam = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(arg0.getPosition().latitude, arg0.getPosition().longitude))
                .zoom(obj_map.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                .tilt(obj_map.getCameraPosition().tilt)
                .bearing(obj_map.getCameraPosition().bearing)
                .build();
        obj_map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(obj_cam));
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You can simplify this by passing your `obj_map.getCameraPosition()` to the Builder constructor. That initializes the Builder with the existing target, zoom, tilt and bearing:

`CameraPosition obj_cam = new CameraPosition.Builder(obj_map.getCameraPosition())`