# GoogleMap change Camera's Center

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have a googlemap.
On the Top of a googlemap I have another layout.
My problem is, The pinpointed location is covered by my Another layout.
How can I change the center of the map.
(Pls see example below at my photo).

So far this is my code.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
    gMap = googleMap;

    if (gMap != null) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(App.getShopLat()), Double.parseDouble(App.getShopLng()));
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(App.getShopname());
        gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

    }
}
```

I Want to achieve the Letter "B" picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061524/5923606

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(Lat, Lon))
    .zoom(12)
    .build();
gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need CameraUpdate class and set the new LatLngBounds something similar to this

```
// Width and height are calculated for your screen 
public static CameraUpdate newLatLngBounds(
    LatLngBounds bounds, int width, int height, int padding)
```

Here is the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#changing_camera_position) for changing map camera position. And it clearly states that you can't use pre-layout.

Comment: What should i put on those params?and how will i implement this to my current code?thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply add **.target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)** 
The location that the camera is pointing at target.

**Example:**
`CameraPosition cPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)) //Sets the center of the map
    .zoom(18)
    .build();`
`map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cPosition));`