# Map marker position with animateCamera to screen location x, y

Tags: android, google-maps

**Dears,**

I have a map view that covers the whole screen. On the top of it, there is a view pager. 
The view pager consist of two parts, top 40% and bottom 60%, the top one is just a transparent view.

While swiping the view pager, marker displayed on map should be located to middle of transparent top view 40%.

This image describe the story:

[image: Sketch]

How to achieve this?
I tried this, but with no luck:

```
public void FollowVehicle(clsFollowMode vehicle){
     final LatLng vehiclePosition = new LatLng(vehicle.getLatitude(), vehicle.getLongtitude());
     Marker vehicleMarker = myGMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(vehiclePosition)
                                .title(vehicle.getDeviceName())
                                .snippet(String.valueOf(vehicle.getSpeed()))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_vehicle_follow)));

     float zoom_lvl = myGMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

     double dpPerdegree = 256.0*Math.pow(2, zoom_lvl)/170.0; 
     double screen_height = (double) mapContainer.getHeight(); 
     double screen_height_30p = -20.0*screen_height/100.0; 
     double degree_30p = screen_height_30p/dpPerdegree;

     LatLng centerlatlng = new LatLng( vehiclePosition.latitude + degree_30p, vehiclePosition.longitude );

     myGMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( centerlatlng, 15 ), 1000, null);
}
```

Any help? the above solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764002/how-to-center-the-camera-so-that-marker-is-at-the-bottom-of-screen-google-map).

Regards,

Comment: So what is the problem? what do you mean by no luck? how is it works now?

Comment: When the pager opens for the first time, it does not centralized to the first marker, but when I move to other pages it does, further, when I back again to first page for second time, it works fine. Moreover, any change for the zoom between the page and another caused a fault centralization for next marker. I think I'm facing problem when this code in the Zoom Level (I guess). Any suggestion? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then your problem is the fact that you placed the map as full screen fragmnet, and on top of this you placed the `ViewPager`. as a result when you center on the marker the map does that but the marker is under the `ViewPager`.

You can trick the map into thinking that it has a smaller size then it really is, by using the [`GoogleMap.setPadding`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method,  you can read more about it here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_padding

Comment: Hi, first I want to confirm your understanding to my problem, second, I tried your suggestion by setting the `GoogleMap.setPadding` method by the 40% transparent view of the `ViewPager` as follows: `myGMap.setPadding(transGap.getLeft(), transGap.getTop(), transGap.getRight(), transGap.getBottom());`, nothing change, it still centralize behind the `ViewPager` at the center of the whole screen. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Got it :), I use 60% view to set bottom padding only, and it works perfect: `myGMap.setPadding(0, 0 , 0, bottomview.getHeight());`, Thanks

Comment: Great, told ya this is what you need : )