# Rotate google map according to bearing with fix marker in center

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude, marker

I am trying to implement google maps in my application.

**Requirement:**

While driving my marker icon should be fixed in center of screen (facing towards north always) while the map should move left right bottom and rotate when user turn on a street.

How I am trying to do it as

```
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 5));

        float bearing = getBearing(Lastposition,newPosition);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(newPosition)
                .zoom(15)
                .bearing(bearing)
                .tilt(0)
                .build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));



    public static float getBearing(LatLng from, LatLng to) {

    Location fromLocation = new Location("");//provider name is unnecessary
    fromLocation.setLatitude(from.latitude);
    fromLocation.setLongitude(from.longitude);

    Location toLocation = new Location("");//provider name is unnecessary
    toLocation.setLatitude(to.latitude);
    toLocation.setLongitude(to.longitude);
    Log.i("Bearing",fromLocation.bearingTo(toLocation)+"");
    return fromLocation.bearingTo(toLocation);
}
```

**Results:**

Marker moves on the path but camera itself does not move according to driver turns on streets. I hope i was able to make things understandable.Please help out what can be issue or better solution for it.Thanks

Comment: See if this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272870/2711811 . Also, I think you mean "direction of travel always up".  You may have to post an example of what you're after.

Comment: @Andy this help me a lot. thanks dude.