# How can I change google Map view and current location marker?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, view

I am trying to set my android App Google Map View to bottom of the screen but it does not changes its position to bottom. I am trying to replicate a Google Map/Waze kind of navigation feature in my Android Application.

**Marker Code:** Here I set the marker position to custom position according to user position and set a custom icon.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(userlatLng);
markerOptions.icon(markerIcon);
markerOptions.rotation(userlocation.getBearing());
markerOptions.title("Current Position");
markerOptions.anchor((float) 0.5, (float) 0.5);
markerOptions.flat(true);
currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

**Camera Position:** I am changing the Camera position accourding to User current location with the zoom level of 20.

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(userlatLng)
            .zoom(20)
            .bearing(userlocation.getBearing())
            .tilt(45)
            .build();
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

I wanted to ask how can I drop the icon to the bottom of the screen and show the remaining route on wide angle screen.

[Default view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQx0j.png)

[Required view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCF6v.png)

Comment: This answer may give you some direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272870/2711811 . Essentially center the camera on an "offset" point calculated using current screen projection.