# Camera map never goes to offset position

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I working with maps and in my app I have a SupportMapFragment filling whole screen. When a marker is clicked a popup shows. This popup when shown get 75% of the screen.

Because of that I need to center the marker in the remaining 25%. To do that I'm using setOnClusterItemClickListener from CluserManager. But no matter what I do the marker always goes to the center of the SupportMapFragment.

I tried most solutions from this answer:

[How to center the camera so that marker is at the bottom of screen? (Google map api V2 Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764002/how-to-center-the-camera-so-that-marker-is-at-the-bottom-of-screen-google-map)

No success. Below I put some code. What I would like to know is why marker continues to go to center of the screen.

```
 clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem myItem) {

    LatLng location = myItem.getPosition();


    /*float zoom_lvl = googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
    double dpPerdegree = 256.0*Math.pow(2, zoom_lvl)/170.0;
    double screen_height = (double) mapFragment.getView().getHeight();
    double screen_height_30p = 50.0*screen_height/100.0;
    double degree_30p = screen_height_30p/dpPerdegree;
    LatLng centerlatlng = new LatLng( location.latitude, location.longitude  + degree_30p);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(centerlatlng), 1000, null);*/

    Projection projection = googleMap.getProjection();
    LatLng markerPosition = myItem.getPosition();
    Point markerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(markerPosition);
    Point targetPoint = new Point(markerPoint.x, markerPoint.y - mapFragment.getView().getHeight() / 4);
    LatLng targetPosition = projection.fromScreenLocation(targetPoint);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetPosition), 1000, null);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just need to return true. Returning false tells to ClusterManager always centers the mark on screen.