# How to get coordinates from the center of Google Maps SDK V3

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to get the coordinates after user move the map.

This is what I tried:

```
...

googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {

        selectedLat = mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
        selectedLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;

        Log.d("maptest", "Coords: " + selectedLat + "," + selectedLng);

    }
});

...
```

It's returning some coordinates but they're wrong. Thousands of km away.
It seems that it returns only the center of map, not the center of camera view.

How can I get the camera view center coordinates?

Comment: why you got both latitude from target?

Comment: You're right... Thanks

Comment: is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764002/how-to-center-the-camera-so-that-marker-is-at-the-bottom-of-screen-google-map/16764140

Comment: My code is working, but I really didn't see that little mistake. A lot of hours programming. I'll get a rest haha